# WordPress block editing support

Tags: wordpress, function, themes

I have a "Loan calculator" block and I want to change the calculating formula and the values. I cannot access the code. How can I access the code and change the block?

I use Elementor for editing. I tried switching in WordPress editor and then went to "Pages", but there was no code.

Comment: Is the loan calculator something you implemented?  How did it get into the page to begin with.  That isn't functionality that is built into Wordpress.

Comment: The "Loan Calculator" is a block, part of 'Pylon' theme. It is built for using in WordPress. I add it as a block.

Comment: My guess is that you'll need to edit the source code for that theme then.  That isn't something that you can do through the WordPress interface, but rather be editing the files installed along with WordPress in your hosting.

Comment: You mean I should change the source code on downloaded files, and then upload the theme again?

Comment: Or SSH into your webserver and edit the files there directly.

Comment: I do not know how to SSH